# Split filenames with python

Tags: python, file

I have files that I want only 'foo' and 'bar' left from split.

```
dn = "C:\\X\\Data\\"
```

files

```
f=  C:\\X\\Data\\foo.txt
f=  C:\\X\\Dats\\bar.txt
```

I have tried `f.split(".",1)[0]`

I thought since dn and .txt are pre-defined I could subtract, nope. 
Split does not work for me.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

How about using the proper path handling methods from os.path?

```
>>> f = 'C:\\X\\Data\\foo.txt'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(f)
'foo.txt'
>>> os.path.dirname(f)
'C:\\X\\Data'
>>> os.path.splitext(f)
('C:\\X\\Data\\foo', '.txt')
>>> os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))
('foo', '.txt')
```

Answer (score 4):

simple Example for your Help.

```py
import os
from os import path

path_to_directory = "C:\\X\\Data"

for f in os.listdir(path_to_directory):
    name , extension = path.splitext(f)
    print(name)
```

### Output

```sh
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 3):

To deal with path and file names, it is best to use the built-in module `os.path` in Python. Please look at function `dirname`, `basename` and `split` in that module.

Answer (score 3):

Using python3 and [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
import pathlib
f = 'C:\\X\\Data\\foo.txt'
print(pathlib.PureWindowsPath(f).stem)
```

will print: 'foo'

Answer (score 1):

These two lines return a list of file names without extensions:

```
import os
[fname.rsplit('.', 1)[0] for fname in os.listdir("C:\\X\\Data\\")]
```

It seems you've left out some code. From what I can tell you're trying to split the contents of the file.

To fix your problem, you need to operate on a list of the files in the directory. That is what `os.listdir` does for you. I've also added a more sophisticated split. `rsplit` operates from the right, and will only split the first `.` it finds. Notice the `1` as the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

another example:

```
f.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the numbers from the filename follow the steps.

For example filename is test12345.txt

```py
import re
filename=test12345.txt
filenamenumbers=re.findall(r'\d+',filename)
#remove the special symbols
finalfilenamenumbers=re.sub(r"['\([{})\]']",str(filenamenumbers))
```

Comment: its not perfect, but points for trying.   It was OS problem from 12 yrs ago.